# Broken links in Force Layout with Threshold Slider in d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to reproduce the example `B is for breaking links` in [this tutorial](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/).

This is the code I have so far :

**output.json**

The file output.json is in [this link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/0rklzhesd0p3ot9/output.json).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

h3 {
    color: #1ABC9C;
    text-align:center;  
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var graphRec, node, link;

d3.json("output.json", function(error, graph) {
   if (error) throw error;
   graph = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph));

   force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

   graphRec = graph;

   link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

   node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

//adjust threshold
function threshold(thresh) {
    graphRec.links.splice(0, graphRec.links.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
            if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {graphRec.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);}
        }
    restart();
}
//Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes
function restart() {
    link = link.data(graphRec.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    node = node.data(graphRec.nodes);
    node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).call(force.drag);
    force.start();
}

</script>

<form>
    <h3> Link threshold 0 <input type="range" id="thersholdSlider" name="points" value = 0 min="0" max="10" onchange="threshold(this.value)"> 10 </h3>
</form>
```

Now the graph looks as expected in the start, but when I try to move the slider, all the links are broken and all the nodes are detached.

Even when I get the slider back to `0`, the links are still broken.

What is the problem ? And how can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've overwritten references to 'graph' (the current graph) with 'graphRec' (the unfiltered version it uses to restore links) in the `restart` and `threshold` functions

Above version:

```
function threshold(thresh) {
    graphRec.links.splice(0, graphRec.links.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
            if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {graphRec.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);}
        }
    restart();
}
//Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes
function restart() {
    link = link.data(graphRec.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    node = node.data(graphRec.nodes);
    node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).call(force.drag);
    force.start();
}
```

Looking at the original example it should be:

```
function threshold(thresh) {
    graph.links.splice(0, graph.links.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
            if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {graph.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);}
        }
    restart();
}
//Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes
function restart() {
    link = link.data(graph.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    node = node.data(graph.nodes);
    node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).call(force.drag);
    force.start();
}
```

So what happens in your code is all the links are erased from `graphRec.links` by splicing them all out. Then it attempts to loop through that now empty array, but of course nothing happens. (Which is just as well, as the code would add them to the end of the same array, so it would keep increasing in size and the loop would never end.) Then in `restart` it joins that empty array to your graph so all your links disappear and will never return as the links have been erased from the underlying data.

So, restore the original code for the two functions is my answer.

PS assigning `graphRec = graph` to preserve a copy of the original graph won't work as it only makes a shallow copy, they would point to and edit the same arrays. You'd need to do `graphRec = {links: graph.links.slice(), nodes: graph.nodes.slice()}` or use the jsonifying method in the original code

Comment: I have already tried that, but the problem I found in the original code was mainly about the scope of the `graph` variable. In the original code, the `JSON` data was hardcoded in a `<script>` tag so it wasn't a problem. In my case, I need to get my data from a different `JSON` file. In this case, the scope of the variable `graph` from the function `d3.json(error, graph)` is limited to the precited function, thus the need to add another variable `graphRec` with a wider scope.

Comment: With your solution, @mgraham, I get a `TypeError: graph is undefined` when using the slider. @user1885868 I'd like to know you finally solved the problem.